# Why is my simple Jetty server handling only 1 request at a time?

Tags: java, multithreading, http, jetty, jetty-9

I'm using Jetty for the first time.

My server setup:

```
server = new Server(port);
ContextHandler testContext = new ContextHandler();
testContext.setContextPath("/test");
testContext.setHandler(new TestServlet());

ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[]{ testContext});

HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{ contexts, new DefaultHandler() });

server.setHandler(handlers);
server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
server.start();
```

Test code:

```
public class TestServlet extends AbstractHandler
{
    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        System.out.println("a");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("b");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("c");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    }
}
```

If I visit `localhost/test` on two different tabs, the 2nd request waits until first is finished, so my log looks like:

```
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

Why are they the requests not processed in parallel?

Comment: @GhostCat hopefully correct, tried to run on 2 browsers simultaneously, thanks

Comment: yes, it does, thanks

Comment: ain't no problem bro, appreciation goes for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that people run into this from time to time (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857102/embedded-jetty-9-handle-one-request-at-a-time) for example).

But as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587660/how-does-jetty-handle-multiple-requests) nicely explains - jetty is **built** for serving users in parallel.

So the answer is: this is not a **jetty** problem - but a user error; for example by running the requests from a single browser (and that browser internally serializes the requests).

Comment: in my case I tried with different browsers, and still don't get it in parallel